CSP Module Issue in patch upgrade magento version 2.4.6-p6
ISSUE: Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src assets.adobedtm.com *.adobe.com data: www.googleadservices.com www.google-analytics.com googleads.g.doubleclick.net analytics.google.com www.googletagmanager.com *.newrelic.com *.nr-data.net geostag.cardinalcommerce.com 1eafstag.cardinalcommerce.com geoapi.cardinalcommerce.com 1eafapi.cardinalcommerce.com songbird.cardinalcommerce.com includestest.ccdc02.com www.paypal.com www.sandbox.paypal.com www.paypalobjects.com t.paypal.com s.ytimg.com www.googleapis.com vimeo.com www.vimeo.com *.vimeocdn.com *.youtube.com https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/ https://www.google.com/recaptcha/ *.avada.io js.braintreegateway.com assets.braintreegateway.com c.paypal.com pay.google.com api.braintreegateway.com api.sandbox.braintreegateway.com client-analytics.braintreegateway.com client-analytics.sandbox.braintreegateway.com *.paypal.com songbirdstag.cardinalcommerce.com *.yotpo.com http://127.0.0.1/ *.aptrinsic.com 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-hashes' 'nonce-eWxoeXBpYW11OXVrbXdlbnp4cGh6cWx1Y3ZiemdtNGQ=' 'sha256-W5akSSK6LD5BjIlNICMcXaUObQSRAaj6bs7JHADURBA=' 'sha256-3qVqeAdyxxTdPkkRzqapjGkAUYLahxSrB7Mdup+GPQ0=' 'sha256-2rvfFrggTCtyF5WOiTri1gDS8Boibj4Njn0e+VCBmDI=' 'sha256-p8MCfMHqrovsjRYU9z0bU17dd0z81k/fVbGrtBBiM9g=' 'sha256-0pk2s4oXwBELlC6IBVb3nNaM2PjfjwI2N6OGIX5lx8Y=' 'sha256-nkEZknO0IxNxY/CkTMBhjNhwPvglpYumjx31B4fjkY8='". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-A6CktM4r1NQCpDicl7xMeooXesWySEqXStbkj79JbAM='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
Issue Reference: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/en/docs/commerce-knowledge-base/kb/troubleshooting/payments/admin-create-order-page-in-csp-restricted-mode
Tried CSP whitelist using csp_whitelist.xml file
<csp_whitelist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Csp/etc/csp_whitelist.xsd">
    <policies>
        <policy id="script-src">
            <value id="self">'self'</value>
            <value id="unsafe-inline">'unsafe-inline'</value>
            <value id="sha256-script-hash">'sha256-nkEZknO0IxNxY/CkTMBhjNhwPvglpYumjx31B4fjkY8='</value>
            <value id="google" type="host">*.google.com</value>
            <value id="g-static" type="host">*.gstatic.com</value>
            <value id="google-apis" type="host">*.googleapis.com</value>
            <value id="maxcdn" type="host">*.bootstrapcdn.com</value>
            <value id="fontawesome" type="host">*.fontawesome.com</value>
            <value id="data-script" type="host">'self' data:</value>
            <value id="relieffactor" type="host">*.relieffactor.com</value>  
            <value id="local" type="host">http://127.0.0.1/</value>           
        </policy>
        <policy id="style-src">
            <values>
                <!-- Google APIs -->
                <value id="google-apis" type="host">*.googleapis.com</value>
                <value id="maxcdn" type="host">*.bootstrapcdn.com</value>
                <value id="fontawesome" type="host">*.fontawesome.com</value>
                <value id="plyr" type="host">*.plyr.io</value>
                <value id="g-static" type="host">*.gstatic.com</value>
                <value id="data-style" type="host">'self' data:</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="img-src">
            <values>
                <!-- Data Scheme - Base64 Encoded Images -->
                <value id="data-image" type="host">'self' data:</value>
                <value id="g-static" type="host">*.gstatic.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="frame-src">
            <values>
                <value id="vimeo" type="host">*.vimeo.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="connect-src">
            <values>
                <!-- Google Analytics -->
                <value id="google-analytics" type="host">*.google-analytics.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="font-src">
            <values>
                <!-- G Static -->
                <value id="g-static" type="host">*.gstatic.com</value>
                <!-- Data Scheme - Base64 Encoded Fonts -->
                <value id="data-font" type="host">'self' data:</value>
                <value id="maxcdn" type="host">*.bootstrapcdn.com</value>

            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="frame-src">
            <values>
                <!-- Google -->
                <value id="google" type="host">*.google.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
         <policy id="base-uri">
            <values>
                <!-- G Static -->
                <value id="g-static" type="host">*.gstatic.com</value>
                <!-- Data Scheme - Base64 Encoded Fonts -->
                <value id="data-font" type="host">'self' data:</value>
                <value id="maxcdn" type="host">*.bootstrapcdn.com</value>

            </values>
        </policy>

    </policies>
</csp_whitelist>```

Please suggest any solution to skip CSP whitelist issue


In Magento version 2.4.6-p6, Content Security Policy (CSP) is enabled by default on the checkout page, which can cause issues with the functionality of checkout. To resolve this, you need to add the following code to the etc\config.xml file in your custom module. This code configures CSP to be in report only mode, allowing the checkout to work as expected:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2020 Grazitti. All rights reserved.
*/
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../Store/etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <csp>
          <mode>
           <storefront_checkout_index_index>
           <report_only>1</report_only>
          </storefront_checkout_index_index>
       </mode>
    </csp>
 </default>
</config>


I need a solution for admin areas

As suggested above you will make it report only which ignore the error and give warning only but  Incase you want to restrict the scripts then Need to add script from admin then you have to add the "hash" in csp_whitelist.xml file.

This may not answer your question, but I had to disable the CSP module to get my self-signed SSL certificate to work locally (I wanted to test SSL locally before putting it on a VSP).
